# How can i make several queries without side effects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how can i improve this code, because sometimes it make to stuck my applicacion, i want to improve with promise.all or something like that

```
for (const property in objs) {
    let suma = 0
    for (const value in objs[property].value) {
      const snap = await gameRef
        .where(property, '==', value)
        .get()
      objs[property].value[value].counts = snap.size 
      suma += snapshot.size 
    }
    objs[property].counts = suma
  }
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and this part you miss i think   objs[property].value[value].counts = snap.size

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Promise.all` to wait for all results, you can do something like this:

```
const promises = [];
for (const property in objs) {
  for (const value in objs[property].value) {
    const promise = gameRef.where(property, '==', value).get();
    promises.push(promise);
  }
}
const snapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
let sum = 0;
snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
  sum = sum + snapshot.size;
})
```

Comment: sorry but you are missing this part      objs[property].value[value].counts = snap.size 
      suma += snapshot.size 
    }
    objs[property].counts = suma

Comment: Did you try the code and did it calculate the sum correctly now? If so, did you try adding the other part in this structure yourself?